# get matched elements indexes from string object

Tags: java, regex

Lets say, search string is

**"Hellothisissanjayhelloiamjavadeveloperhello"**

And Search pattern is  *** Hello***  I want to get starting and ending indexes of each matched strings like

first Hello--- start index=0, end = 4,

second Hello-- start index=22, end = 26,

like this

Comment: What is your question. And what you tried for solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the text by space.
2. Iterate and group the word matching hello with corresponding index.
3. corresponding index will be "Hello Start index".
   4  corresponding index + 3 will be "end".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this solution. Just simple `String#indexOf` method in a `while` loop will give you start and end index.

```
String input = "Hellothisissanjayhelloiamjavadeveloperhello";
String kw = "hello";
String len = kw.length();
String pos = 0;
int i;

while ((i=input.indexOf(kw, pos)) >= 0) {
    pos = i +len;
    System.out.println("Starting index=%d, end=%d\n", i, pos);
}
```